# Is there an explicit formula for $\left(xx^T\right)^{-1}$ with $x\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\left\{0\right\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\left\{0\right\}$. Obviously, $$A:=xx^T$$ is symmetric and positive definite. Hence, $A$ is invertible. Can we find an explicit formula for $A^{-1}$?

Comment: The matrix $xx^T$ has rank $1$, so it can't be invertible if $n>1$.

Comment: It is positive *semi* definite, never positive definite

Comment: This matrix has eigenvalues $x^Tx$ (with multiplicity $1$) and $0$ (with multiplicity $n-1$), so it's not invertible for $n>1.$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously the matrix $xx^T$ is ***not*** positive definite if $n>1$, because it has rank $1$.

A simple way to see it has rank $1$ is by observing that any vector $y$ which is orthogonal to $x$ belongs to the null space of $A=xx^T$.

Comment: You're right. What if $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ with $x^Ty>0$ and we define $$B:=xy^T\;.$$ Can we say anything about the invertibility of $B$ in this case?

Comment: @0xbadf00d It still has rank at most $1$.